# how is a php rule written where a mysql field can equal multiple php variables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have tried all these ways and it's not working...

```
if ($row['dropdate1'] == "".$datemon."" || $row['dropdate1'] == "".$datetue."" || $row['dropdate1'] == "".$datewed."" || $row['dropdate1'] == "".$datethu."" || $row['dropdate1'] == "".$datefri."") {}

if ($row['dropdate1'] == ".$datemon." || $row['dropdate1'] == ".$datetue." || $row['dropdate1'] == ".$datewed." || $row['dropdate1'] == ".$datethu." || $row['dropdate1'] == ".$datefri.") {}

if ($row['dropdate1'] == "$datemon" || $row['dropdate1'] == "$datetue" || $row['dropdate1'] == "$datewed" || $row['dropdate1'] == "$datethu" || $row['dropdate1'] == "$datefri") {}

if ($row['dropdate1'] == $datemon || $row['dropdate1'] == $datetue || $row['dropdate1'] == $datewed || $row['dropdate1'] == $datethu || $row['dropdate1'] == $datefri) {}
```

UPDATE:

this question is not about the database query and getting it to pull in the correct records.  the correct records are already displaying.  this is about how the records show on html/php page in the html table.

if the record has 1 dropdate then only one row shows.

if the record has 2 drop dates then it will show as 2 rows in the table.

all the way up to 6 rows if the record has 6 drop dates.

so if just one drop date is equal to one of the php variables i mentioned above, i just want to display that row, but instead all the drop date rows show up for that record.

so let's say $datethu = 01-23-2014 and this date is in one of the records under any of the dropdate fields, let's say dropdate4.

the table will display like this:

```
drop  id    company  jobname    dropdate     bunch-of-other-columns
1     260   abc      whatever   01-02-2014   ...
2     260   abc      whatever   01-09-2014   ...
3     260   abc      whatever   01-16-2014   ...
4     260   abc      whatever   01-23-2014   ...
5     260   abc      whatever   01-30-2014   ...
6     260   abc      whatever   02-06-2014   ...
```

the above would be accurate if all the dropdates were one of the php variables.  but since only one of the dropdates contains one of the php varibales, then the table should look like this:

```
drop  id    company  jobname    dropdate     bunch-of-other-columns
4     260   abc      whatever   01-23-2014   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all of the possible values in an array and then use `in_array()`:

```
$values = array($datemon, $datetue, $datewed, $datethu, $datefri);
if (in_array($row['dropdate1'], $values)) {
    // we have a match
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that values are what you expect them to be? If your values are correct this will work.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn´t do the selection within php. Try something like this:

```
 $qouery = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE yourColumn IN ('".$datemon."', '".$datetue."', '".$datewed."')";
```

And than perform your query and work with the result.

Kind regards

Comment: Worth noting that if the php vars are user-provided, you better make sure they are correctly escaped to avoid SQL injection attack.

Comment: of course, i for myself use a framework where every sql call will be masqueraded and encoded before delivery to the server. The above example was ment to show the principle.